# Postgres Sql Connection in Ofbiz web application

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jdbc, groovy, ofbiz

I am developing my first web app in Ofbiz framework with psql database.
I added the postgresql-8.1-404.jdbc2.jar jdbc driver jar to /framework/entity/lib/jdbc folder and made necessary corrections to entityengine.xml file and now trying to access the table in the database with the following groovy code.

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)

import groovy.sql.Sql

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
def dbUrl      = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname"
def dbUser     = "postgres"
def dbPassword = "root"
def dbDriver   = "org.postgresql.Driver"

def sql = Sql.newInstance(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)
// even Groovier...
sql.eachRow('SELECT * FROM tablename') {
  println  it.party_id }
```

but it throws the following exception

```
[java] Exception: java.sql.SQLException
[java] Message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname
```

help to resolve my problem...Thank You.

Comment: Why on earth would you use the 8.1 JDBC driver, not one released this decade? (I don't think that's the problem, but it sure won't help).

Comment: You don't need the `@GrabConfig` as you aren't using `@Grab`.  That looks like the postgres drivers aren't in the classpath

Comment: then how to set the classpath for the postgres driver...